# I want to deduct the product ingredients from the inventory

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables orders, inventory and ingredients. i want the orders(products) to automatically deduct its ingredients from inventory every time it is ordered.

ORDER_ITEMS

```
    +----------+--------+-----------------+
    | order_id |item_id |    item_name    |  
    +----------+--------+-----------------+
    |     1    |   1    |      coffee     |
    +----------+--------+-----------------+
    |     1    |   2    |      shake      | 
    +----------+--------+-----------------+
```

PRODUCT_INGREDIENT:

```
    +--------+-----------------+--------+
    |item_id | ingredient_id   | amount |
    +--------+-----------------+--------+
    |   1    |      123        |  10    |
    |   1    |      124        |  15    |
    |   1    |      125        |  10    |
    |   2    |      124        |  15    |
    |   2    |      123        |  10    |
    |   2    |      126        |  15    |
    +--------+-----------------+--------+
```

INVENTORY:

```
    +--------+-----------------+--------+
    |  id    | ingredient_id   | amount |
    +--------+-----------------+--------+
    |   1    |      123        |  100   |
    |   2    |      124        |  100   |
    |   3    |      125        |  100   |
    |   4    |      126        |  100   |
    +--------+-----------------+--------+
```

i tried this but i can't seem to make it work

```sql
UPDATE INVENTORY i, PRODUCT_INGREDIENT p 
SET i.amount = i.amount - p.amount
WHERE i.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id
```

I want my inventory to look like this after the order has been made.

INVENTORY:

```
        +--------+-----------------+--------+
        |  id    | ingredient_id   | amount |
        +--------+-----------------+--------+
        |   1    |      123        |   80   |
        +--------+-----------------+--------+
        |   2    |      124        |   70   |
        +--------+-----------------+--------+
        |   3    |      125        |   85   |
        +--------+-----------------+--------+
        |   4    |      126        |   90   |
        +--------+-----------------+--------+
```

Comment: You might think orders should come into the update.

Comment: It's a very unusual schema.

Comment: I would create another table that stores the ingredient names to avoid repetitions. [DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: i changed the ingredient_name to ingredient_id to avoid repetition of ingredient names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the syntax for MySQL `update ... join`:

```
update inventory i 
inner join product_ingredient p 
    on i.ingredient_name = p.ingredient_name 
set i.amount = i.amount - p.amount
```

Note: this would make more sense if table `orders` was involved in the query. Also, the way this table looks, it seems to contain order *items* (so it would be better named  `order_items`); and, it is probably missing a column named `order_id` that uniquely identify an order. So, given a paramter that represents an `order_id`, your query would look like:

```
update inventory i 
inner join product_ingredient p 
    on i.ingredient_name = p.ingredient_name 
inner join order_items o 
    on o.item_id = p.item_id 
set i.amount = i.amount - p.amount
where o.oder_id = ?
```

---

**Update**

For a one shot update, you probably want aggregation:

```
update inventory i 
inner join (
    select ingredient_id, sum(amount) amount
    from product_ingredient
    group by ingredient_id
) p on i.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id 
set i.amount = i.amount - p.amount
```

Comment: @EthanGarcia: yes this gets closer to making sense. The only difference now with my second query is that I named the table `order_items`, while yours is called `orders`. You should be able to test this.

Comment: the first one you gave only deducted the ingredient once. the inventory shows sugar= 90,milk = 85, creamer=90, ice=85

Comment: sorry, they turned the wifi at my uni off. I tried the query with my revised database but it only deducted once

Comment: @EthanGarcia: welcome... You might consider deleting the duplicate question you posted afterwards. Also if my answer was helpful please consider upvoting it (you seem to have enough reputation to do so now).

Comment: I just realized when I implemented it on the system I'm working on, but the WHERE CLAUSE is missing, I need it so only the ones inside the order_id can be deducted from the inventory

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this automatically on the insert of an order consider a trigger.

```
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t after insert on orders
for each row
begin
    update inventory 
        join (select ingredient_name,amount from product_ingredient pi where pi.item_id = new.item_id) s 
        on s.ingredient_name = inventory.ingredient_name    
        set inventory.amount = inventory.amount - s.amount
        where 1 = 1;                
end $$
delimiter ;
```

After the inserts to orders inventory looks like this

```
+------+-----------------+--------+
| id   | ingredient_name | amount |
+------+-----------------+--------+
|    1 | sugar           |     80 |
|    2 | milk            |     70 |
|    3 | ice             |     85 |
|    4 | creamer         |     90 |
+------+-----------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note if you can change or delete the order after insertion then you need update and delete triggers trigger as well.

Comment: A subquery seems unnecessary.

Comment: I don't know what delimiter is, but the query
" update inventory i 
inner join product_ingredient p 
    on i.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id
inner join order_items o 
    on o.item_id = p.item_id 
set i.amount = i.amount - p.amount
where o.order_id = 1 " deducts both sugar and milk only once.

Comment: This trigger will fire on an insert - running the update part in isolation may not give the result you expect. And the result is as you asked for.